# What is another word for "predictor"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is another word for "predictor"?

> "...peer alcohol use is one of the strongest predictors of adolescent alcohol use."

The word "indicator" isn't quite right, because I am looking for a word that literally means "predicts" or "forecasts" (forecaster is a bit awkward in this sentence, but something with a similar meaning would be great).

Comment: Perhaps it could be described as ***one of the strongest correlates*** - for that is what they effectively mean, don't they? 'Peer alcohol use' doesn't actually *predict* things does it?

Comment: @WS2  It is a predictor, that's the word used in statistics and technical studies.  And the child of an alcoholic parent has a greater probability of becoming an alcoholic in its adult life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an epidemiologic context, **"predictors of"** could be replaced with **"risk factors for"**

> - [**"risk factor"**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/risk%20factor) - "something which increases risk or susceptibility"
>     e.g. -  A fatty diet is **a risk factor** for heart disease.

or **"an indicator of"**

> - [**"indicator"**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indicator) -  "something that provides an indication, esp of trends."
>
> e.g. - Reduced galectin-3 expression is **an indicator** of unfavorable prognosis in gastric cancer.

Comment: risk factor is a great option! Thank-you so much for your input @Centaurus!

Answer (score 0):

Consider **forerunner**.

> Definition: an omen; a sign or indication beforehand of something to
>   follow; a portent; a premonitory symptom
>
> Example: *Cruelty to animals is often a* forerunner *of domestic abuse or
>   abuse against children and other types of activities of violence
>   against human beings*.